# Android webgl concept?

Tags: android

is it possible to develop the webgl applications in android?which version of android is supporting this means which version of mobile browser is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Just to update this, Firefox mobile, aka Fennec, now runs on high-end android phones and supports webgl. Some of the demos will run a little slowly... this is the case for most processing.js 3d code since it seems to not use highly optimized webgl. Some of the demos, especially those written in the "thin layer" webgl frameworks like spidergl run pretty well.

Your android device must support arm7 instruction set to run Fennec. This rules out low-end phones, but Evo class, tablets, etc will run it fine.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like none of the Android browsers support it at the moment but it is [planned for the Android browser](http://blogs.sonyericsson.com/developerworld/2011/02/24/webgl-support-in-the-android-web-browser/) (no eta specified) and also for [Firefox Mobile](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Fennec/Features/webgl) (july 1, 2011).